# Django TemplateSyntaxError: 'endblock', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I'm unsure where my syntax error is, if you can please spot it that would be great.

```
{% extends 'budget/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
            <ul class="z-depth-1">

            {% for transaction in transaction_list %}
            <li>
                <div class="card-panel z-depth-0 transaction">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col l5">
                            <span class="title"> {{ transaction.title }}</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col l5">
                            <span class="title">{{ transaction.amount }}</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col l1">
                            <span class="title bold">{{ transaction.category.name }}</span>
                        </div>

                        <a href="">
                            <i class="material-icons right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            {% endfor $}


        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

And 'budget/base.html' looks like this:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>BudgetProject</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried looking at similar problems and I'm fairly certain the syntax for the for loop is correct. My code was working until I added the {% for x in y %} {% endfor %}

Comment: You have a typo: `$}`

Answer (score 1):

you did a small mistake, please remove the $ sign from the {% endfor $} and add % instead. and in last line of your code replace {% endblock content %} with {% endblock %} so your code will look like as below:

```
    {% extends 'budget/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
            <ul class="z-depth-1">

            {% for transaction in transaction_list %}
            <li>
                <div class="card-panel z-depth-0 transaction">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col l5">
                            <span class="title"> {{ transaction.title }}</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col l5">
                            <span class="title">{{ transaction.amount }}</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col l1">
                            <span class="title bold">{{ transaction.category.name }}</span>
                        </div>

                        <a href="">
                            <i class="material-icons right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}


        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```